# Один ко многим mysql php

Tags: mysql, база-данных, связывание-данных

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
+------------------+
|foodname          |
+------------------+
| id | description |
+------------------+

+------------------------------------+
| product                            |
+------------------------------------+
| id | productdesc | massa | id_food |
+------------------------------------+
```

Cвязь один ко многим. Помогите составить запрос на выборку что бы выводилось только то описание(productdesc,massa) которое соответствует ID продукта из первой таблици.
 Данный запрос не помог! Выводит все продукты хотя вроде бы все правильно запилил)

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
           product.productdesk
         , foodname.ID  
         FROM product, foodname 
         WHERE product.idfood = foodname.ID';
```

Comment: У Вас имеются опечатки в SQL запросе, но если он работает и работает неверно, то, пожалуйста, покажите на конкретном примере, что именно требуется вывести

Comment: Запрос должен выбрать все продукты из таблицы 2  которые по idfood подходят к продуктам из таблицы 1 Вот код:function get_product_by_food_index() {

    global $link;

    $sql  = 'SELECT product.productdesk, foodname.id  FROM product, foodname WHERE product.idfood = foodname.id ';

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $food = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

    return $food;Код отрабатывает и вытаскивает инфу из бд но она не соответствует id продукта

Comment: Да, этот запрос конечно вернет все продукты и к ним все foodname, по крайней мере он именно так написан. И да, описания будут соответствовать продуктам. приведите тестовые данные, текущий результат и что вы ожидаете на самом деле

Comment: array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Сыр" [1]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Огурец" [1]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Курица" [1]=> string(1) "2" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "Майонез" [1]=> string(1) "1" } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Чеснок" [1]=> string(1) "3" } [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Чеснок" [1]=> string(1) "3" } } Вот массив который я получаю.Я хотел бы что бы выводились те продукты которые по значению idfood соответствуют id блюду из первой таблицы

Comment: Проще говоря мне нужно что бы при выборе определенного блюда мне выбрались все продукты из которого он сделан)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product.productDesk, foodname.ID
FROM foodname 
LEFT JOIN product ON product.idfood = foodname.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  fn.id,
  p.productdesk,
  p.massa
FROM foodname as fn
LEFT JOIN product as p 
    ON p.id_food = fn.id
```